# What is the French word for mathematical variable?

Tags: informatique, mathématiques

[ Ce qui suit est la motivation ou l'inspiration pour la question ]

> I wish to translate the 200 most common LaTeX commands from portmanteaus of English phrases into full un-abreviated French phrases.

```
ε = \varepsilon
  = \variableepsilon
  = \la phrase française va ici
```

---

Quel serait un nom français utilisé pour des choses qui varient dans le temps ou changent de sens dans différents contextes ?

Comment: "variable" à mon avis.

Comment: Parfois "inconnue", mais dans le cadre de la résolution d'une équation.

Answer (score 3):

In Latex, varepsilon is short for *var**iant** epsilon,* and not variable epsilon. To be precise, the usual epsilon (\epsilon) is ϵ and the variant (\varepsilon) is ε. The long French form thus should maybe be called *la variante d'epsilon.*

Comment: C'est donc juste une _variante_ de représentation à l'affichage? J'ai complètement raté cet aspect :-) Si c'est le cas, _variante_ est plus approprié, effectivement.

Answer (score 1):

Je pense que "variable" convient, de façon très standard. On peut aussi utiliser "inconnue" dans le cadre de la résolution d'une équation.